# Convertir archivo a XML y mantener nombres de atributos

Tags: c#, xml

Estoy utilizando *C#*, y necesito convertir una lista *XML* a un arreglo para así mandarlo por medio de *WCF* y esos datos desplegarlos en el cliente web.

Del siguiente arreglo solo necesito mantener `Name` y `Url`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Configuration>
  <Cameras>
   <Camera Name="Camera1" Url="Camera1" Width="600" Height="800" />
   <Camera Name="Camera2" Url="Camera2" Width="600" Height="800" />
</Cameras>
</Configuration>
```

Estuve tratando con este código...

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load(
    Path.Combine(
        Path.GetDirectoryName(
            typeof(ConfigListenerSecondary).Assembly.Location
        ), configFile
    )
);
XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("//Camera");
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{
    string Name = xn["Name"].InnerText;
    string Url = xn["Url"].InnerText;
    Console.WriteLine(Name, Url);
}
```

... pero me despliega el siguiente error:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando haces:

```
xn["Name"]
```

o

```
xn["Url"]
```

... estás buscando un nodo hijo con esos nombres. Esto no es lo que quieres. En tu caso, lo que quieres es leer los *atributos* `Name` y `Url`.

Esta es la forma correcta de hacerlo:

```
XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("//Camera");
foreach (XmlElement ele in xnList)
{
    string Name = ele.GetAttribute("Name");
    string Url = ele.GetAttribute("Url");
    Console.WriteLine($"{Name}, {Url}");
}
```